# Is the insertion order for an array every going to be changed after performing a map

Tags: arrays, typescript

If I have an array and I want to call map() to that array. Will the result returned from map ever going to have different order from array?

```
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
const mappedArray = array.map((num) => {
   return num * num;
})
console.log(mappedArray);
```

The mappedArray will ever be [1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81]
or it is possible that it changes to something else (not the same order)?

What if I make an API call inside the map like the following

```
const mappedArray = array.map(async (num) => {
   return await api(num);
})

// remote API
function api(num) {
   return dynamoDbClient.getItem(num);
}
```

Comment: I don't think "insertion order" is what you mean.  If you write `const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]; array[8] = 9; array[7] = 8;` the insertion order is not the same as the order of the indices... since you are inserting the `9` before you insert the `8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `map` will always iterate through the array in order. Unless the array is changed elsewhere in your code, the order of the resulting array will not change. The output will always be the same if the input is the same.

Run this code 1000 times and the array will be the same every time.

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
const mappedArray = array.map((num) => {
   return num * num;
})
console.log(mappedArray);
```

Comment: What if it is like this
const mappedArray = array.map(async (num) => {
   return await apiCall(num)
})

Comment: That depends on the api results. Does `apiCall` return the same value every time? If so, then map will return the same result every time.

Comment: If the api, for example, is getting results from MySQL without ordering them, then you could have a situation where the api call might not return a consistent array.

Comment: The apiCall is something like get record from Dynamo DB according to the input number.

Comment: Using async isn't going to mutate the array